# Graphics class seems to be overriding JFrame/JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I've been having some trouble understanding this whole structure of JPanel, JFrame, and graphics class, and extending and overriding and such. I seemed to have everything working, until I added the graphics class and then my buttons and such on my JPanel/JFrame didn't show up anymore. I figured out it has something to do with overriding or super? But I really need some clarification. Thanks so much!

I've narrowed down the code a bit for easy viewing.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class windowBuild extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int energy = 4;
    private JButton btnClaw = new JButton("Claw");
    private Image bg;
    private boolean loaded = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                windowBuild frame = new windowBuild();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String which = e.getActionCommand();
            if (which.equals("Claw")) {
                energy = energy - 1;
                System.out
                        .println("Player one's dragon clawed the opponent. Dragon's energy is now at: "
                                + energy);
            }

        }

    }

    public void loadImage() {
        bg = new ImageIcon("C:\\res\\dragonDuelBackground.jpeg").getImage();
        loaded = true;
        repaint();
    }

    public windowBuild() {
        ButtonHandler bh;
        System.out.println("Starting frame...");
        bh = new ButtonHandler();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Dragon Duel",
                TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.CYAN));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        btnClaw.setBounds(273, 511, 109, 39);
        contentPane.add(btnClaw);
        btnClaw.addActionListener(bh);

    }
//********************************************************************
//  public void paint(Graphics g) {
//      if (loaded) {
//          g.drawImage(bg, 400, 400, null);
//      }
//  }
//***************Uncomment this and the code won't work anymore**********
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Uncomment this and the code won't work anymore

Don't override paint() of a top level container (JFrame, JDialog...). Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the panel to the frame. Don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...).

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial for more information and examples.

Answer (score 2):

1. Avoid extending directly from `JFrame`.  You're not adding any new functionality to the frame and you're restricting the re-usability of your UI if you do (as you can't add frames to anything else)
2. Don't override `paint` of top level containers.  There are lots of good reasons, but the main problem is that the frame containers a number of different layers (`JLayeredPane`, `contentPane`) which may paint over anything you do
3. You MUST call `super.paintXxx` to ensure that the paint chain remains intact.

Instead, create a seperate class (extending from something like `JPanel` for example) and override it's `paintComponent` method.  Or better still.  Simple use a `JLabel` to display the image

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Also, I don't see any where you are calling `loadImage`, so the image is never loaded

I would also recommend that you take a read through [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) using `ImageIO`, which will throw an `Exception` when it can't read the image file, which is far more useful then `ImageIcon` which simply fails silently

**Updated with simple example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TestGraphics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGraphics();
    }

    public TestGraphics() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int energy = 4;
        private JButton btnClaw = new JButton("Claw");
        private BufferedImage bg;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            try {
                bg = ImageIO.read(new File("dragon.gif"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            ButtonHandler bh;
            bh = new ButtonHandler();
            setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Dragon Duel",
                    TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, Color.CYAN));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setOpaque(false);
            buttonPane.add(btnClaw);

            add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            btnClaw.addActionListener(bh);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return bg == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (bg != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - bg.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - bg.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(bg, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String which = e.getActionCommand();
                if (which.equals("Claw")) {
                    energy = energy - 1;
                    System.out
                            .println("Player one's dragon clawed the opponent. Dragon's energy is now at: "
                            + energy);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ps- You better have very good reason to be not using a layout manager

Comment: Could you change the code and show me. I understand  what you're saying, but now I'm struggling with what to put where, inside the main class or in its own?